# Will my App be available worldwide, or only in my country?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm going to upload an free App to the App store in a few weeks. I come from Holland. Will it be available worldwide, or just here? I'm concerned because App Store always shows me Apps from my country in the top lists, and I realld doubt that so many Apps come from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's up to you. When you submit your app for review in iTunes Connect, you are asked to choose which countries' stores will list it.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I really thought they're releasing it whery they "think" it fits good.